# Add condition to AngularJS map function

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I'm using the below to loop through an array and add a property to each item of the array.

```
$scope.addresses = $scope.addresses.map(function(address) {
      address.location = "X";   
      return address;
});
```

this at the end will return all the items. How can I add a condition to the loop? so I can check a property and the based on that property return only certain addresses where that property is `true`?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `filter` function

You can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Basically `filter` is a function the gets a boolean function as a parameter (let's call it `f`), and returns an array with all the items that the `f` returns true for.

For example:

```
var mapped = $scope.addresses = $scope.addresses.map(function(address) {
      address.location = "X";   
      return address;
});

var filtered = mapped.filter(function (address) {
    return address.location.length > 5;
});
```

`filtered`  will hold a collection of the addresses that have a location with more than 5 characters.

Comment: Can you please expand

Answer (score 0):

use filter

```
$scope.addresses = $scope.addresses.filter(function(address){
  return address.location === x;
})
```